# Regex - match other sentence except this sentence

Tags: regex

I currently have this document which structured like this.

```
Google URL : www.google.com
One time fee : 5000
Cost price of boat :$29242 NLC by Micheal
Total paid for boat (inc. recond) : 
Payment due : 
Expected receipt $ :
```

I would like to use regex to match other words in the file except this sentence

```
Cost price of boat :$29242
```

I have limited knowledge with regex so this task is impossible for me to do.

My first attempt was trying to use negative lookahead which ends in utter failure.

Here is my not so working regex

```
^(?!Cost\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s[:][$]\d+)
```

If you can guide me to the right path that would be great. Thanks!

Language : prce (php)

Comment: which language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the multi-line option like this

`(?m)^(?!Cost\s+price\s+of\s+boat\s+:).*`

then add the `.*` which will grab the line if it doesn't start with what's
in the assertion.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following regex:

```
(?!Cost\s+price\s+of\s+boat\s+:)(?<=^|\v).*(?=$|\v)
```

or

```
(?!Cost\s+price\s+of\s+boat\s+:)(?<=^|\v).*
```

Tested on **regex101**:

https://regex101.com/r/Ecp0kp/2

https://regex101.com/r/u6BE87/3